# Google Map In Android Studio

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm an Android app developer and now I'm building an application for a protection company
My problem is , Can I locate all people who use my app on google Map ?

Comment: please research before adding here just Google it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

broadcast location of every user who install the app in every 30 minutes and mark all the location into your map..

You could set up an **AlarmManager** for every 30 minutes and check getLastKnownLocation. However, the last known location is only actively updated if at least 1 app is registered for location updates- so you'll still have to register yourself to make sure that variable is updated.

Then, send the location to the API. Then finally, you fetch and mark all the location into your google map.. :)

Comment: Thank you so much
But what service do I want to look for to locate customers ?

Comment: you can use AlarmManager and BroadcastReceiver in android.. for backend site, maybe you can use Pusher to autoupdate in your Map realtime..

Answer (score 0):

You can get the location of the user (if he/she accepts the permissions), then send it to your server.